# Irssi authenticates via SASL, still attempts to log in as username

Tags: irssi

So I'm using Irssi 0.8.17 with Fedora 22 (installed through dnf) and configured SASL authentication and SSL for Freenode. I can authenticate using the credentials I've supplied in an `~/.irssi/sasl.auth` file (automatically generated via `/sasl set Freenode primary-nick password PLAIN`). However, I am for some reason automatically logging in as my local username in addition to my irc nick and I can't figure out how to stop the unwanted behavior.

I took the cap_sasl.pl script from Freenode's website https://freenode.net/sasl/sasl-irssi.shtml .

Added the Gandi ssl cert and converted it from a crt to a pem file.

created `~/.irssi/sasl.auth`

I stripped my `~/.irssi/config` to the bare minimum

```
servers = (   {
    address = "chat.freenode.net";
    chatnet = "Freenode";
    port = "6697";
    use_ssl = "yes";
    ssl_verify = "yes";
    ssl_cacert = "~/.irssi/certs/*.pem";
    autoconnect = "yes";   }, );

settings = {   
    "fe-text" = { actlist_sort = "refnum"; };
};

chatnets = {
    Freenode = { type = "IRC"; };
};
```

However, I still log in to Freenode twice and I don't understand why. I have not touched the stuff `/usr/share/irssi`.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue, change `chatnets` to

```
chatnets = {
    Freenode = { type = "IRC"; nick="IRC-NICK" };
};
```

Update:
also, I removed write permissions `chmod -w ~/.irssi/config` to prevent irssi from creating a new core settings line with real-name et al in it. YMMV.